# How Can I Change Close/Minimize/Max buttons in unity?

Tags: unity, minimize, style

I am working on a Linux distro and I was wondering how I can change the images of close/minimize/max buttons. I do not want to move them. Just change the style.
Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: They're usually set by your window manager theme (Ambiance, Radiance, Adwaita, etc.), whose files are usually in `/usr/share/themes`. Check the output of `find /usr/share/themes/ -iname '*close*'`

Comment: So are you running Ubuntu then, or a different Linux distribution? If it is Ubuntu then which version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

These buttons are usually image files (.png) located in `/usr/share/themes/[name of current theme]/unity/assets`.

EDIT: corrected path to themes folder after muru's comment.

Comment: Thanks. But when I drag and drop I file into that file in Ubuntu nothing happens. I assume it is because of user privileges. How can I change my self to root or something along those lines? Thx.

Comment: You are right: an ordinary user is not allowed to modify that folder. Use a terminal command, either for copying (`sudo cp /sourcefile /targetdirectory/`) or to start a graphical interface under root (`sudo nautilus`).